# What exactly is your 'garrison' used for and is it still relevant in the Legion expansion?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just started playing WoW again, and haven't played since before 'garrisons' were in the game.

What exactly are the intended purposes of your garrison? And is the garrison still relevant in the newest expansion 'Legion'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your garrison is the main hub of your activities in the Warlords of Draenor expansion.

It provides you with the beginnings of many vital WoD questlines, crucial crafting (profession-based) resources, and is where you launch Missions (Followers and--later--your Shipyard fleet) from. All of these things contribute significantly to the core Warlords of Draenor experience. Further, a well-managed Garrison was an extremely lucrative source of gold, facilitating trading between players for highly desirable resources.

However, now that Warlords of Draenor is at an end and Legion has started, the importance of the Garrison has significantly diminished, similar to how the launch of WoD diminished and marginalized the importance of your Halfhill farm back in Pandaria. There are still a significant number of unique things (Battle Pets, Engineering toys, etc) that can only be obtained through the use of your garrison, but it is no longer a core piece of the present expansion's experience.

Comment: I added a second part to my question about whether it is still viable in the new expansion as that's probably the most relevant part. You mentioned there was something similar that essentially became deprecated, the 'Halfhill', so now that Legion is out, is there something new that is similar to the Halfhill or Garrison?

Comment: @pay I am not going to play WoW for the Legion expansion (taking time off; raiding 6-12 hours per week for 7+ years kinda burnt me out!) so I can't tell you the exact details. However, the idea is that [Legion Class Halls](http://www.wowhead.com/guides/class-halls-overview) replace Garrisons in spirit.

Comment: yes, Order Halls are similar to Garrisons in terms of followers and missions to help power up artifacts etc, however the professions focus of the Garrisons has been mainly removed. This means Garrisons will still be relevant to a degree for Professions (especially ones your chracacter does not have), and to obtain certain pets, toys, achievements and other items, but doing it will give you no real benefit in Legion.

Comment: If you're just leveling through Draenor on your way to Legion content, I'd mostly ignore the garrison except as a convenient hearth, and rush to 98, at which point you can head out to the Broken Isles.

Comment: It should be noted that the garrison can have a portal to Ashran, which has portals to major cities. When your hearthstone is down this is how I get around

Comment: I still visit my garrison regularly even as of Shadowlands. Out of the various order halls, class halls, etc., the WoD garrison was the only one that actually felt like I was in charge of something. The way everyone calls you "Commander" and the way the guards all salute you... it just feels FINALLY like I'm a champion of Azeroth and not just some random adventurer.